# Detecting a Fling or a Tap

Tags: android

I have a ViewSwitcher and I'm having trouble in determining between a Fling and a Tap.   It is a FlashCard program and I want to have swipe that will change cards and aTap that will flip a card.

But when I try to swipe/fling, it always recognizes it as a tap.

Can anyone provide some general logic that I can use to solve this problem.

TIA,  Trey

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and use the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for changing cards.
The flipping of cards via tap could be done the same way, that you are currently doing it.

Using Fragments is a bit of work in the first place, but it's paying back once you want to make your app ready for different device categories i.e. tablets / TVs.

Even Fragments have been introduced in Android 3.0, you can use the [Android compatibility library v4](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to support devices down to Android 1.6.

Comment: Thanks Surfer, but I need to support 2.23 and Fragments are avail in 3.0.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mentioning the compatibility library. Will edit in a moment.